# Whenever I select anything it just shows the shader thing at the bottom of the screen

Tags: shaders, object-mode, select

[image]Whenever I select anything it just shows the shader thing at the bottom of the screen. I am in object mode in layout and I can't do anything or move anything! not sure what to do. Here is the scene I downloaded.
https://open3dlab.com/project/34717/

Comment: What do you mean "it just shows the shader thing at the bottom"? Would you mind showing us a screenshot of the issues you are having instead of letting us download a scene and hope we might have the same problem - what is not necessarily the case or maybe we just don't see what you mean?

Comment: NVM I added it. Doesn't matter what I click it just shows the shader at the bottom I can;t actually select anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select objects. As you can see in your screenshot in the top left of the *Shader Editor* window, there is the name of the selected object: "TFGstaircase". You just cannot see the outlines of what you are selecting because the *Show Overlays* option in the *3D Viewport* is disabled.

[image: show overlays]

Comment: OMG I'm an idiot lol thank you so much for that!